# Spring: why HttpServletRequest.getReader and getInputStream giving null from POST request to spring HttpRequestHandler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring HttpRequestHandler handling a POST request. However, the HttpServletRequest is null.

I'm aware that I need to call one or the other, but it looks like BOTH are null. So what gives? Is it possible that spring has rudely grabbed the stream? If so, how can I get the data in a POST request?

```
class MyRequestHandler extends HttpRequestHandler {
  override def handleRequest(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
    println("HANDLE " + request.getReader())  // NULL
    println("HANDLE " + request.getInputStream()) // NULL
  }
}
...
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class MyConfig {  
  @Bean(name = Array("/endpoint"))
  def endpointHandler(): MyRequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler()
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the InputStream object is null when no data is posted.

Why was no data posted? A case of RTFM:

```
var mockMvc: MockMvc = ...
...
val result = mockMvc
  .perform(
    post(url, postData)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

needs to look like this

```
val result = mockMvc
  .perform(
    post(url)
      .content(postData)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

The subsequent params to post are URL parameters: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RC1_to_3.2.0.RC2/Spring%20Framework%203.2.0.RC2/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html